# Como ejecutar archivos desde repositorio remoto en Jenkinsfile o pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, pipeline

Tengo que crear un pipeline que ejecute varios archivos .py y .sh que estan guardados en subcarpetas de un repositorio en github, soy nuevo con esto se las pipelines y no se si es posible, he conseguido hacer pipelines llamando a archivos locales pero no consigo hacer la pipeline para que llame a subcarpetas de un repositorio remoto en github.

pongo un ejemplo sencillo del tipo de pipeline que he creado, me gustaria que en vez de llamar a un archivo local lo hiciera a uno remoto:

```
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            
            sh '/home/Test.sh' 
            echo'test ejecutado'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Gracias Arcanis! así lo haré

Comment: me respondo a mi mismo porque he encontrado la solución, y es practicamente lo mismo que tenia pero desde la dirección correcta:

stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            
            sh ". /testing/Test.sh" 
            echo 'test ejecutado'
        }
    }
}

Comment: interesante puedes agregarlo como respuesta y deberías dar una explicación del por porque resuelve tu error. eso ayuda a ganar reputación ...

Comment: merci Arcanis, hecho!

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins baja automaticamente el repositorio antes de ejecutar el archivo, por lo que es tan simple como llamar a la ruta correcta donde se baje.